# Specify large set of IDs in SOQL query

Tags: soql, bulk-api

I have an object with around 2 million records and list of IDs that I need to extract.

The list is around 20k entries. Surely I can't just chug them into query parameter?

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Just a suggestion, couldn't you create a set of IDs and add all the IDs you have in to the set and later use this set in SQOL , WHERE Id IN :IDSet. Sorry if my understanding of the scenario is wrong and this, dosen't help.

Comment: @Stygon That solution requires `Apex`. Bulk API is dataloader, etc.

Comment: Yeah just tested in Apex, it does work with a SET of 20k ids. Might have a think how can I use this. Can you submit bulk requests via Apex?

Comment: You can process csv files with it. Haven't played around with that platform feature but I'm sure there are plenty of resources around it.

Comment: Actually, looks like a job for Force CLI, but the real question is how do you pipe the query parameter? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: The new SOQL limit is 100,000 characters, but you only get 4,000 characters for the where clause in the new limits. You'll definitely want to use the retrieve call (now available in [REST](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections_retrieve.htm)) to get up to 2,000 records at a time.

---

The raw SOQL limit is 20,000 characters, so you can't make a raw dynamic statement that exceeds this value. You'll need to chunk your query into multiple parts. In theory, you'll get around 1,000 rows, maximum, depending on how many fields you use (and assuming you 15-character length ID values). If possible, consider using the [retrieve](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_retrieve.htm) call, which *only* works by ID value, but allows 2,000 rows at once to be retrieved (larger than you could do by raw SOQL). You'll have quite a bit of API calls using this method, since it's not limited by the 20,000 character limit.

Comment: Are all these limits still current?  And do they apply to the Bulk Api 2.0?  If I use the bulk API 2.0 to create 10,000 person accounts, would I really need to make 10 separate queries to collect all the PersonContactIds?  Or might there be a better way (such as somehow getting it in the success response with the accountIds)?

Comment: @BrianKessler The job, when complete, provides all of the ID values. The [limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_soslsoql.htm) have changed, you can query more fields, but a smaller where clause (now 4k characters, about 470 Ids maximum).

Comment: Cheers for the fast response!  Not sure what you mean by "The job, when complete, provides all of the ID values"; it doesn't seem to include the `PersonContactId` value, neither by default nor if I include an empty value for it among the values I'm inserting.  Alas, I don't need more fields at the moment as I only need the one... I could query by record create time instead...but then it could still be a problem if I will only get 1,000 records... could we do something with offset?  I suppose I should create a new question for this....

Comment: @BrianKessler oh, right, you get just the ID. You could `retrieve()` to get 2k records at a time, that'd probably be the best way to retrieve the info you want.

Comment: Is there a way to do retrieve without messing around with SOAP and wsdl files?  And how might we select the records to ensure we get all of them through subsequent calls?

Comment: @BrianKessler You can do this with [REST](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections_retrieve.htm).

Comment: Awesome.... Definitely seems a good alternative to the bulk query API.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly chuck them in the SOQL as a set or use the `OR` operator:

`SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id IN ('00100000001abcX', '00100000001abcY')`

OR

`SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id = '00100000001abcX' OR Id = '00100000001abcY'`

Although be careful as there is a limit of number of characters used in the SOQL string. I think it's something around the 3000 mark (you can find the exact number in the Salesforce Docs).

I'm afraid that you'll have to split the IDs and do this in batches, keeping the character limit under.

> **Update:**
>
> The limit is 20,000 as per @sfdcfox's answer!

Comment: 20,000 characters, or about a maximum of 1,000 unique ID values if you use 15-character ID values. There's a better way, of course.

Comment: A nice hack, if this is a one-off query, is to use Workbench and bump the API version back to the old limits, v37.0 I think.